# Are $\frac{a}{\gcd(a,n)}$ and $n$ always relatively prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

> If $d = \gcd(a,n)$, then $\dfrac ad$ and $n$ must be relatively prime. Prove or
>   disprove.

Do I have to show that they need to be relatively prime and then the inverse that they do not need to be relatively prime? I do not know where to start. I think that they do not need to be relatively prime, but I cannot think of an example.

Comment: If you try some examples, you will find which direction you want to go.  Have you done that?  What have you found?

Comment: So an example of d=gcd(a,n) would be 100=gcd(10,5) right? Then a/d would be 10/100 and n would be 5. But they would not be relatively prime because they can share factors like 2/100 or 5/10.

Comment: No, gcd$(10,5)=5$  Then $\frac ad=2$ which is coprime to $n$.  You have many things backwards here.  $\frac ad$ will always be an integer, because $d$ divides $a$.

Comment: Good grief!!! this post is 3 years old!  Why on earth was this edited and revised?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest counterexample is $n^2$ and $n$.

Comment: For $n>1$. So I'd say $a=4$, $n=2$ is the simplest case.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=6$ and $a=12$. Then $d=\gcd(12,6)=6$. But $\frac ad = \frac{12}6 = 2$.

Comment: "proof does not hold"?

Comment: I think I probably meant to write statement. In any case, I deleted the offending sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Though the given answers provide some good counterexamples but this question is not totally about giving *counterexamples* (As you say: **Prove or Disprove**).

I shall use many variables here, so read with a little care.

**CLAIM**: If $d=gcd(a,n)$, then both the possibilities are open (i.e.  $\frac{a}{d}$ and $n$ may be coprime or may be not).

Let's see the *proof* now:

Since $d=gcd(a,n)$ so we can say that $a=dk$ and $n=dl$, where $d,l$ are coprime integers (WHY ??  This is your exercise).

Now, $\frac{a}{d}=k$ and as known, $n=dl$. What we are trying to find is that  $k,dl$ are coprime or not.

Notice that I have already mentioned that $k,l$ are coprime, but no such conclusion is made regarding k and d. So, if k and d share a factor then $\frac{a}{d}$ and $n$ will not be coprime and if k and d are coprime then $\frac{a}{d}$ and $n$ will also be coprime.

**Conclusion**:

If $n$ is a factor of $a$ and on dividing $a$ by $n$ there is still something in $a$ which was also in $n$ then $\frac{a}{d}$ and $n$ will not be coprime otherwise they will be coprime.

**Examples**: The given examples illustrate the conclusion very well.

In @abnry's example: $n$ divides $n^2$  and after that, we are still left with the $n$.

In @zelzy's example: $6$ divides $12$ and after that we are left with $2$ which is a factor of $6$.

Comment: Disproving a statement of the form "X must hold" amounts precisely to giving an example where X does not hold (not showing that X can never hold). And if this is possible (as is the case here), then proving the statement is not possible. To **prove or disprove** involves clearly selecting one of these options; your answer fails to do that (even though one ends up understanding which one it is).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, I do not say that other answers are wrong, I just said that A generalised result is always preferable against an example. Hope you won't disagree on that.

Answer (score 2):

Let us disprove a slightly weaker statement:

> given integers $a, b$, not both zero, $$\text{either } \gcd\left(a, \frac{b}{\gcd(a, b)}\right) = 1 \text{ or }\gcd\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)}, b\right) = 1$$

As a counterexample, just take $a = 2^{2} \cdot 3 = 12$ and $b = 2 \cdot 3^{2} = 18$.

Answer (score 2):

$\gcd(a,n)| a; \gcd(a,n)|n$ so let $a' =\frac a{\gcd(a,n)}$ and $n' = \frac {n}{\gcd(a,n)}$.  So $a = a'*\gcd(a,n)$ and $n = n'*\gcd(a,n)$.  This "separates" $a$ and $n$ into distinct components.  This is always a good place to start.

[  Clearly $\gcd(a',n') = 1$ because if $k|a'$ and $k|n'$ then $k*\gcd(a,n)|a$ and $k*\gcd(a,)|n$ and so $\gcd(a,n)$ is not the *greatest* common divisor.]

So are $\frac a{\gcd(a,n)}= a'$ and $n = n'\gcd(a,n)$ always relatively prime?  Well, $n'$ and $a'$ have no common factors.  But do $a'$ and $\gcd(a,n)$ have a common factor?

Well, they might have.  If $a$ had a higher power of factor than $n$ did.

Example:  Suppose $\gcd(a,n) = k^m*d$, $a = \overline{a}k^{m+s}d $ and $n = n'k^m*d$.  (In other words, $a' = k^s*\overline{a}$.)  Then $\frac {a}{\gcd(a,n)} = k^s\overline{a}$ and $n = n'*k^m*d$.  These are not relatively prime.

Example: $\gcd(a,n) = 4^3*7$ and $a = 27*4^5*7$ and $n = 143*4^3*7^3$.  Then $\frac {a}{\gcd(a,n)} = 27*4^2$ while $n = 143*4^3*7^3$ and they are not relatively prime.

A far easier example will be: $a = n^2$ and $n =n$  Then $\gcd(a,n) = n$ and $\frac a{\gcd(a,n)} = \frac {n^2}{n} = n$.  $n$ and $n$ are, of course, not relatively prime.

Answer (score 1):

i am writing again because my first solution has confused some people.  DON'T MIND!!!

$GCD(a,n)=d$

by the definition of GCD there is no other common factor in $a,n$

now we would try to prove that if some factor is common between them then it must be in $d$

now let $\frac{a}{d},n$ are not coprime

$\implies$GCD(\frac{a}{d},n)=x$

$\implies x|\frac{a}{d}$

$\implies x|a$

&    $x|n$

$\implies x|GCD(a,n)=d$

we had eliminated every thing common in $a,n$ by dividing $a$ by $d$ from $a$ so $\frac{a}{d},n$ are coprime

Answer (score 0):

let us assume that $\frac{a}{d},n$ are not relatively primes

$\implies n,\frac{a}{d}$has a common factor.let this factor be $x$

$\implies x|a,n$

as $x$ is a factor of $\frac{a}{d}$

$\implies$ $x$ survives

$\implies$ $x$ is not contained in $d$ with that multiplicity by which it can  eliminate it completely from $a$

$x$ must not contained in $n$ if contained in,it must be in $d$

a contradiction!!!

Comment: "X survives".  X survives what?  What does that mean?  "X is not contained in d".  Why not?  If d = 4, a = 8 and X = 2 then 2 is a factor of 8/4 =2 and 2|4.  Not a  problem.  "x must not contained in n if yes it must be in d".  Um,.. If "yes" to what?  I can not parse this sentence.  I dont know what "yes" means.  "a contradiction".  Where?  Let $a = 12; n = 10$.  then a/d = 6 and n = 10 and they have 2 as a common factor.  This is not a contradiction.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. No, it isn't.

Comment: @fleablood, :) :) :)

Comment: $x$ survives means that $x$ is a factor of $\frac{n}{d}$